# Passing Void into a class as a pointer then executing its contents

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments, void

How can I pass a function as an argument and then execute it. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class Foo{
private:
    void (*external);
public:
    Foo(void (*function)()){ *external = *function; }
    ~Foo(){ }
    bool Execute(){ 
        *external(); // Somehow execute 'external' which does the same thing with 'function' 
        return true
    }
};

void pFnc(){
printf("test");
}


int main(){
 Foo foo = Foo(&pFnc);
 foo.Execute();
 return 0;
}
```

This is not working of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef void(*FN)(void);
    Foo(FN fn) : fn_(fn) {};
    bool Execute()
    {
        fn_();
        return true;
    }
    FN fn_;
};

void pFunc(){
    printf("test");
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo(&pFunc);
    foo.Execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    void (*external)();
```

Your original declaration is a pointer to void, not a pointer to a function returning void.

Answer (score 1):

Set it with

```
external = function;
```

and execute with

```
external();
```

Also, external has to be declared as a function pointer `void (*external)()`. Otherwise, you have to cast between function- and void-pointer.